# Hex code lose his format

Tags: hex, diacritics

Can somebody say me what is the problem:

I will print out a hex file on the "Epson TM-t88II" printer, but after this all my "Umlaute" (ä/ö/ü/ß) lost its format and are black dots, etc.

My Hex code for an ü is "FC". Is it false?

Comment: Are you aware of the distinction between character codes, text encodings and glyphs?

Comment: No, can you send me a link with this?
At the moment is my hex File encoded with ANSI.

Comment: Try encoding it with UTF-8 or UTF-16. Here's a relevant link that explains it in depth: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I have try it with UTF-8, it dont work... I have convert it with "Notepad++". Can you tell me an good programm, which can convert the file to utf-16?

Comment: After checking the printer you have, it _might_ not implement the UTF-8 or -16 standards. You don't happen to have another receipt printer on hand you can test it with?

Comment: I have try it on 2 receipt printers. It dont work... It looks so: zur³ck "³=ü" I'm pissed off...

Comment: Can't you just spell it as "zurueck"? I know it looks inelegant, but if you can't get the umlauts, it's the only option you have left.

Comment: I think its nonprofessional. That is a receipt and that will see customers. I will looking for an good answer.

Answer (score 0):

&00FC is "ü" in many encoding formats, but not all. If your printer does not know what encoding you're using, it may well not understand what you want to print.

Exactly what are you sending to the printer? And what application are you printing from?

The following may also be of interest.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpfully:D
Do you know, what is the correct hex code for "ü" by the printer "Epson TM-t88II" ?